# Replacing string that have a pattern what uses :

Tags: c#, regex

i am trying to replace some string pattern in a string, but I cant archive my goal..

input:

```
:randomword: NO REMOVE :random_word_word:
:random: NO REMOVE :random:
NO REMOVE :random:
:random: NO REMOVE
```

expected:

```
NO REMOVE
NO REMOVE
NO REMOVE
NO REMOVE
```

actual

```
''
''
'NO REMOVE'
'NO REMOVE'
```

current regex

```
Regex.Replace(input, ":.+:", "");
```

Comment: `":.+:"` => `":.+?:"` / `":[^:]+:"`. `.Trim()` would be of help, I believe.

Comment: I'd go with `\s*:.*?:\s*` to also remove trailing/leading spaces. GL